# dirent.h casuing problems with ShellAPI.h

Tags: c++, windows

I have a function:

```
SHFileOperationFunc(string item1, string item2, int operation, CuTest *tc)
```

It is used to do operations (move, delete or copy) directories. It works fine. But i am now trying to use stuff from dirent.h. When I include the file it causes huge problems with stuff from ShellAPI.h I use in SHFileOperationFunc. I got dirent.h as per http://www.softagalleria.net/dirent.php.

After I include the file I get errors like:

```
error C2065: 'FO_DELETE' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'FO_COPY' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'FO_DELETE' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'FO_DELETE' : undeclared identifier
```

These are defined in ShellAPI.h. When I hover over them in VS it says the value they have so it is seeing them. Anyone know why including this file is having this effect?

Comment: The "hovering" bit is because IntelliSense uses a single symbol database for all files. If the symbol is defined in one of your files, IntelliSense will show that value in all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dirent.h on a Windows machine is unadvisable, it is a Unix header.  The file you downloaded screws up the rest of your #includes.  Either put if *after* `#include <windows.h>` or edit the file and delete the #define for WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN.  Putting that in a header is, well, mean.  It causes a large number of declarations to be skipped in the Windows headers.

Comment: fair enuf. Ill find another way of doing what i want so. cheers